# How to remove a grand piano harp and keep the strings attached?

Tags: piano, strings, bridge

I am planning to turn my old piano into a table, using the cast iron plate/harp with the strings, sound board removed, as the bottom, covered with glass.  I would like to keep the strings.  Seeing as the bridges are connected to the sound board, what are some options for this?

Just remove the bridges and simply tighten the strings?

Comment: Is this related to music or more about furniture?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more appropriate for a site focused on furniture building or related skills.

Comment: Advice from a piano technician is likely to be more useful (and safe) than advice from a cabinet maker though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you've already done the obvious Google search?    But just in case you haven't, here's one source.  (There are several others.)

I'm sure they all emphasise the warning that there's a lot of tension on a piano string and,while the harp is unlikely to break, an individual string might, and you don't want it whipping across your face.

Comment: What a find.  I'm continually amazed by what someone has done and reported about on YouTube.

Comment: "STINGS INTACT"? I already don't trust this person's ability to communicate accurately.

Comment: Was there really a need to leap on this quite interesting piano-specific question as off-topic?